# How to include Objects into Strings in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i want to make a dynamic page in react that use text from another page like this:

[image]

[image]

But every time it shows me [Object Object] instead of Letter and line brake

Comment: It looks like you're confusing JSX and HTML. JSX is JavaScript and can't be interpreted as a string.

Comment: Also, please do not use images of code and instead include a [mcve] inside the question itself, with a clear description of what you're trying to do and what is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You have to stringify the object:

```js
JSON.stringify(object)
```